# POI: Set password to protect from changes

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml

I want to enable password protection on OOXML files using Apache POI.

Via Office programs, while saving the file (`pptx`, `xlsx`, ...) I am able to select `Tools > Options` and there  I have prompts to set passwords for either opening and/or changing the file.

Now I searched severals hours via google and read a few API pages to find the POI methods to do so, but was unable to find anything.

Any idea if this is implemented or a Microsoft speciality becuase they don't give a damn aabout their own standardization?

Edit:
Since the first comment below was pointing to Office 2003 documentation, I may explicitly note: I am talking about XSS* features. I want to secure the OOXML formats from 2007. I look up similiar function on different APIs, but couldn't find those. HSSWorkBook#writeProtect... is known to me.

Comment: check https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html and search about writeProtectWorkbook

Comment: @canillas The method is not available on XSSF types. (you may read the question again)

Comment: Did you read through https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html ?

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes. I was able to set a password to open it, but not to set a password to prevent accidental modification.

Comment: @Isfirs yes...sorry. Have you tried to protect the whole sheet? `sheet.protectSheet(password);` and then enabling locking options? `sheet.enableLocking();` With taht you should be able to do something like `sheet.lock.....(true)`

Comment: @canillas Yes. But that is a pretty specific solution to protect sheets. for example, what Office does is give the file password for opening and/or a password for editing. That way, you can't alter the file. you are forced to open it in read only mode or enter the password to edit the file (applies for ALL types, not just excel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although `Excel` does this in one step while saving the file, this are two steps.

At first the `ReadOnlyRecommended` is set in `/xl/workbook.xml` which looks like:

```
<workbook>
 ...
 <fileSharing readOnlyRecommended="true" userName="user" reservationPassword="DC45"/>
 ...
```

Setting the `fileSharing` element is possible using [org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFileSharing](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTFileSharing.java#CTFileSharing) which you can get/set in `CTWorkbook` which you can get from [XSSFWorkbook.getCTWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#getCTWorkbook--).

The password hash for `reservationPassword` is calculated by a special algorithm. Unfortunately this algorithm is not properly described in most of the Office Open XML specifications. I have found a correct description in [Office Open XML Part 4 - Transitional Migration Features.pdf, page 229 and 230](http://www.ecma.ch/activities/Office%20Open%20XML%20Formats/Draft%20ECMA-376%203rd%20edition,%20March%202011/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%204%20-%20Transitional%20Migration%20Features.pdf#page=229&zoom=auto,86,430).

After this step you will have a workbook with the read only recommended and a password to open with write access.

If done, you now can set the encryption as shown in [Apache POI - Encryption support](https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html).

Example:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.*;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

public class OOXMLEncryptionTest {

 //password hashed using the low-order word algorithm defined in §14.7.1 of ECMA-376
 static short getPasswordHash(String szPassword) {
  int wPasswordHash;
  byte[] pch = szPassword.getBytes();
  int cchPassword = pch.length;
  wPasswordHash = 0;
  if (cchPassword > 0) {
   for (int i = cchPassword; i > 0; i--) {
    wPasswordHash = ((wPasswordHash >> 14) & 0x01) | ((wPasswordHash << 1) & 0x7FFF);
    wPasswordHash ^= pch[i-1];
   }
   wPasswordHash = ((wPasswordHash >> 14) & 0x01) | ((wPasswordHash << 1) & 0x7FFF);
   wPasswordHash ^= cchPassword;
   wPasswordHash ^= (0x8000 | ('N' << 8) | 'K');
  }
System.out.println(wPasswordHash); 
  return (short)(wPasswordHash);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  // Open an Excel workbook and set ReadOnlyRecommended
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelTest.xlsx"));
  CTWorkbook ctWorkbook = workbook.getCTWorkbook();
  CTFileSharing ctfilesharing = ctWorkbook.getFileSharing();
  if (ctfilesharing == null) ctfilesharing = ctWorkbook.addNewFileSharing();
  ctfilesharing.setReadOnlyRecommended(true);
  ctfilesharing.setUserName("user");

  short passwordhash = getPasswordHash("baafoo");
System.out.println(passwordhash); 

  byte[] bpasswordhash = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(passwordhash).array();
  ctfilesharing.setReservationPassword(bpasswordhash);

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelTestRORecommended.xlsx"));
  workbook.close();

  // Now do the encryption
  POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
  EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
  // EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile, CipherAlgorithm.aes192, HashAlgorithm.sha384, -1, -1, null);

  Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
  enc.confirmPassword("foobaa");

  // Read in an existing OOXML file
  OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File("ExcelTestRORecommended.xlsx"), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
  OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
  opc.save(os);
  opc.close();

  // Write out the encrypted version
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("ExcelTestEncrypted.xlsx");
  fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
  fos.close();

 }
}
```

The setting  read only recommendation seems to be general the same for all `Microsoft Office` file types because you will set the read only recommendation while file save in all cases, but behind the scenes it is not. It is very different how `Microsoft` stores this into the files.

In `Excel` it is `ReadOnlyRecommended` in `FileSharing` element of the workbook and is using a very unsafe 2 byte password hash only.

In `Word` it is a `WriteProtection` element in settings part. And it uses a salted password hash using modern encryption methods.

In `PowerPoint`it is `ModifyVerifier` element in the presentation which also uses a salted password hash using modern encryption methods.

The following example shows all three approaches:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.*;

import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.CryptoFunctions;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.HashAlgorithm;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class RORecommendedTest {

 //password hashed using the low-order word algorithm defined in §14.7.1 of ECMA-376
 static short getPasswordHash(String szPassword) {
  int wPasswordHash;
  byte[] pch = szPassword.getBytes();
  int cchPassword = pch.length;
  wPasswordHash = 0;
  if (cchPassword > 0) {
   for (int i = cchPassword; i > 0; i--) {
    wPasswordHash = ((wPasswordHash >> 14) & 0x01) | ((wPasswordHash << 1) & 0x7FFF);
    wPasswordHash ^= pch[i-1];
   }
   wPasswordHash = ((wPasswordHash >> 14) & 0x01) | ((wPasswordHash << 1) & 0x7FFF);
   wPasswordHash ^= cchPassword;
   wPasswordHash ^= (0x8000 | ('N' << 8) | 'K');
  }
  return (short)(wPasswordHash);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  // Open an Excel workbook and set ReadOnlyRecommended
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelTest.xlsx"));
  CTWorkbook ctWorkbook = workbook.getCTWorkbook();
  CTFileSharing ctfilesharing = ctWorkbook.getFileSharing();
  if (ctfilesharing == null) ctfilesharing = ctWorkbook.addNewFileSharing();
  ctfilesharing.setReadOnlyRecommended(true);
  ctfilesharing.setUserName("user");

  short passwordhash = getPasswordHash("baafoo");

  byte[] bpasswordhash = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(passwordhash).array();
  ctfilesharing.setReservationPassword(bpasswordhash);

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelTestRORecommended.xlsx"));
  workbook.close();


  // Open a Word document and set read only recommended aka WriteProtection
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordTest.docx"));

  POIXMLDocumentPart part = null;
  for (int i = 0; i < document.getRelations().size(); i++) {
   part = document.getRelations().get(i);
   if (part instanceof XWPFSettings) break;
  }
  if (part instanceof XWPFSettings) {
   XWPFSettings settings = (XWPFSettings)part;

   Field _ctSettings = XWPFSettings.class.getDeclaredField("ctSettings"); 
   _ctSettings.setAccessible(true); 
   CTSettings ctSettings = (CTSettings)_ctSettings.get(settings);

   CTWriteProtection ctwriteprotection = ctSettings.getWriteProtection();
   if (ctwriteprotection == null) ctwriteprotection = ctSettings.addNewWriteProtection();
   ctwriteprotection.setRecommended(STOnOff.ON);

   ctwriteprotection.setCryptProviderType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STCryptProv.RSA_FULL);
   ctwriteprotection.setCryptAlgorithmClass(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STAlgClass.HASH);
   ctwriteprotection.setCryptAlgorithmType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STAlgType.TYPE_ANY);
   ctwriteprotection.setCryptAlgorithmSid(BigInteger.valueOf(4)); //SHA-1
   ctwriteprotection.setCryptSpinCount(BigInteger.valueOf(100000));

   SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
   byte[] salt = random.generateSeed(16);
   byte[] hash = CryptoFunctions.hashPassword("baafoo", HashAlgorithm.sha1, salt, 100000, false);

   ctwriteprotection.setHash(hash);
   ctwriteprotection.setSalt(salt);
  }

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("WordTestRORecommended.docx"));
  document.close();

  // Open a PowerPoint show and set read only recommended aka ModifyVerifier
  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("PowerPntTest.pptx"));
  CTPresentation ctpresentation = slideShow.getCTPresentation();
  CTModifyVerifier ctmodifyverifier = ctpresentation.getModifyVerifier();
  if (ctmodifyverifier == null) ctmodifyverifier = ctpresentation.addNewModifyVerifier();

  ctmodifyverifier.setCryptProviderType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.STCryptProv.RSA_FULL);
  ctmodifyverifier.setCryptAlgorithmClass(org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.STAlgClass.HASH);
  ctmodifyverifier.setCryptAlgorithmType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.STAlgType.TYPE_ANY);
  ctmodifyverifier.setCryptAlgorithmSid(4); //SHA-1
  ctmodifyverifier.setSpinCount(100000);

  SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
  byte[] salt = random.generateSeed(16);
  byte[] hash = CryptoFunctions.hashPassword("baafoo", HashAlgorithm.sha1, salt, 100000, false);

  ctmodifyverifier.setHashData(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash));
  ctmodifyverifier.setSaltData(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(salt));

  slideShow.write(new FileOutputStream("PowerPntTestRORecommended.pptx"));
  slideShow.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: So far so good, that gave me some insight on how to accomplish this for XSLX. I was looking around on how to access those parts for XWPF and XSSF as well. Seems like CTDocument and CTPresentation doesn't have any FileSharing on them and I have no idea about the OOXML specs (as you do). Any ideas on that?

Comment: Well I could simply answer that this question is too broad to be answered here. But I have updated my answer providing examples for setting read only recommendation for Excel, Word and PowerPoint. Hope it helps.

Comment: That is impressive! I don't know how you know about this stuff, I wasn't able to find any documentation on the usage of anything for that API. Thank you very much! It is running in my application now and is what I anticipated.

Comment: @Isfirs: First source for all modern `Microsoft Office` file formats will be [Standard ECMA-376 Office Open XML File Formats](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm). Then [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/) will be helpful for the low level underlaying objects of  `apache poi`. But the most powerful knowledge base is a ZIP tool using which you can simply unzip the `*.xlsx`, `*.docx` or `*.pptx` files and have a look at the `XML` files within those archives.

Comment: @AxelRichter: I wonder why you haven't used `(short)CryptoFunctions.createXorVerifier1("baafoo")` in your example ... I hope you just haven't known it, opposed to some bug in it ... btw. for browsing through ooxml/ole office files, I've recently started with a [small tool](https://github.com/kiwiwings/poi-visualizer) ... especially for embedded stuff, I think it's more helpful than a zip tool

Comment: @kiwiwings: Correct, I have not known it. Btw.: The example algorithm from the linked  Part 4 - Markup Language Reference - Ecma International - 3.2.12 fileSharing is not correct at all. I have linked the correct one in my answer. But `CryptoFunctions.createXorVerifier1` seems to use the algorithm from 2.3.7.1 Binary Document Password Verifier Derivation Method 1. So only the ones who trust the ECMA documents will be at a lost. Well ;-).